# Is sensor fusion essential for implementing a mobile game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-sensors

I am working on a mobile car game, in which I utilized my phone accelerometer sensor to move the car.

Should I use sensor fusion? I don't need to get the sensor readings, I only need to move and rotate my car according to my phone's movement, and I see that it moves fine.

Comment: This is either opinion based ("Should I do X?") or very short ("Do I need X? No.")

Comment: I wonder if not using sensor fusion will affect the car movement?